# Piping primitives, lists, structs instead of text?

Tags: linux, unix

The inventor of Unix pipes [said](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html),

> This is the Unix philosophy: Write programs that do one thing and do it well. Write programs to work together. Write programs to handle text streams, because that is a universal interface.

Within the same system I'd like to see this concept done with, instead of text streams, an agreed upon binary data format (maybe primitives, lists, structures).  This would avoid each program having to encode data to text only to be parsed again by the next program.

In my mind the programs would have libraries to convert to/from the binary format, or better yet use the binary format natively.

Has anyone created a set of utils in the same spirit as standard Unix utils that does something like above?

Comment: sounds like xml. Besides, binary data exchange does exist as a subset of the unix philosophy, consider `tar -c | tar -x`, `tar -c | ssh someone@somewhere tar -x` etc etc

Comment: I'm not convinced there is much call for this but aside from limiting yourself to one machine this seems like a problem for which a hundred formats have been created already. Removing the endian and such stuff you can look at corba, com, ans, etc.

Comment: JSON is text. \*starts clapping one hand\*

Comment: Good point, mvds, binary streams are supported.  But I'm under the impression that there is no agreed upon format for piping primitives/structs/lists.  Duck, using a binary format does not limit you to one machine architecture.

Comment: Oh, as for XML, it's nice but has a ton of space/processing overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Windows powershell does pretty much this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell

Clearly - I understand that it's not a linux thing, but "somebody" has done this - and yup its pretty powerful.

Comment: Aha, someone did to it!  Per the article, " In Unix the output of one command is piped to the next stage of the pipeline typically as raw text. With PowerShell, the pipeline consists of .NET Objects. Using objects eliminates the need to parse arbitrary text output from one command to extract data since all objects export a consistent interface".  I think it's time for open source to do it as well.